# Duda treeMap en Java

Tags: java, map

Me gustaria saber si cuando hago una lista `treemap` de objetos `Producto` el cual tiene subproductos en herencia tipo:

```
ProductoA
ProductoB
```

¿Podría solo mostrar los `ProductoA`?

Así es como lo creo:

```
public Cataleg(){
    super();
    this.map_catalogo= new TreeMap<String,Producto>();
}
```

Después de hacer un método donde me añaden los productos ya sean `A` o `B`, consigo mostrar todos así:

```
public void mostrarProductos(){
    System.out.println("Productos disponibles en almacen: ");
    for(Producto p : map_catalogo.values()) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Quisiera saber la manera de que solo me muestre los `ProductosA` (que es una subclase de `Producto`).

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. Ahora mientras la gente lee la pregunta y te contesta, puedes pasarte por el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y aprendes un poco mas del funcionamiento de este sitio :D de paso te llevas medallas. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `java` está el operador [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) que determina si un objeto es una instancia de una clase en concreto.

En tu caso deberias usarlo asi:

```
public void mostrarProductos(){
    System.out.println("Productos disponibles en almacen: ");
    for(Producto p : map_catalogo.values()) {
      if( p instanceof ProductoA) {
        System.out.println(p.toString());
      }
    }
}
```

Si la clase del producto `p` es `ProductoA` devuelve `true` y si no `false`

<sub>Nota: no se si lo obviaste por no ser relevante a tu pregunta pero el objeto `p` debería tener un método `toString()` que muestre la información del Producto. Una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13498202/3045491) muy buena explica que pasa si no creas tus propios `toString()` y usas el por defecto de Objeto</sub>

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funciona perfecto :)

Comment: Hola loisb. buena respuesta. Solo te menciono que el enlace que pusistes para el `instanceof` es para WebLogic, que es algo diferente.

Comment: @sstan meca gracias! ni me pispé. Aunque la verdad me molestó que poniendo "instanceOf java" en google no salga la documentacion arriba

Comment: no pude encontrarla tampoco :)

Comment: @sstan (y lois6b por ende) [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) la documentación, revisar la parte *The Type Comparison Operator instanceof*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza gracias! añadido a la respuesta